# Fontspec Slant Units

Tags: luatex, fontspec, slanted

I'm been testing the `FakeSlant` feature of the `fontspec` package. I have a question. The package documentation is not clear what the units are for the `FakeSlant=#` key=value parameter. My guess on the units based off testing is 1/100th of a degree, but I'm not confident about this honestly.

```
\setmainfont{Source Serif 4}[%Available for free on Google Fonts.
    Kerning=On%
    ,SlantedFont={Source Serif 4}
        ,SlantedFeatures={%
            Kerning=On%
            ,FakeSlant=0.18
            }
]
```

EDIT: Did some more testing. It looks like the `FakeSlant` parameter accepts values from `-1` to `1` but I'm still unsure what those values mean exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am wrong, but the slant value seems to be the tangens of the slanting angle. That is, if the font axis is slanted by *x* degrees (0 degrees meaning upright), the slant value would be tan(*x*). Thus, a slant value of 1 represents a slanting angle of 45 degrees (and a value of -1 an angle of -45 degrees).

Compare:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[red] (45:-0.5) -- (45:1);
    \node at (45:0.5) 
        % tan(45deg) = 1
        {\addfontfeature{FakeSlant=1}I};

    % subtraction from 90 degrees in order to make 0 degrees match upright
    \draw[yellow] ({90-20}:-0.5) -- ({90-20}:1);
    \node at ({90-20}:0.5) 
        % tan(20deg) = 0.36397
        {\addfontfeature{FakeSlant=0.36397}I};

    \draw[blue] ({90-5}:-0.5) -- ({90-5}:1);
    \node at ({90-5}:0) 
        % tan(5deg) = 0.08749
        {\addfontfeature{FakeSlant=0.08749}I};
        
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This would probably also explain, why values larger than 1 or smaller than -1 are not possible ...

Comment: Yes, skew is tan: [PDF reference](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/standards/pdfstandards/pdf/PDF32000_2008.pdf), p118

Comment: @Cicada but your previous comment regarding the sin/cos matrix might be valid anyways, since tan can be derived vom sin and cos.

Comment: @User23456234 No, it is skewing, you can easily see this if you look at a wide letter, such as capital M for instance: if you rotate it, the two stems won“t sit on the (same) baseline anymore.

Comment: cos and sin is for rotation

Answer (score 2):

Using the `cm` pdfliteral:

[image: pdfliteral]

MWE

```
pdftex

\protected\def\rbox#1{%
  \setbox0\hbox{{#1}}%
  \setbox2\hbox{%
  \special{pdf:literal q}%
  \special{pdf:literal -1 0 0 1 0 0 cm}\rlap{\copy0}
\special{pdf:literal Q}}%
    \hbox to --1\wd0{\kern--1\wd0\box2\hss}%
}

\rbox{abc $\mapsto $ xyz}

Text text text, $abc\mathbin{\rbox{ $\mapsto$}}xyz$, text text text.
% note the space: >>\rbox{ $<<

\protected\def\rbox#1{%
  \setbox0\hbox{{#1}}%
  \setbox2\hbox{%
  \special{pdf:literal q}%
  \special{pdf:literal -1 0 -0.2 1 0 0 cm}\rlap{\copy0}
\special{pdf:literal Q}}%
    \hbox to --1\wd0{\kern--1\wd0\box2\hss}%
}

\rbox{abc $\mapsto $ xyz}


\protected\def\rbox#1{%
  \setbox0\hbox{{#1}}%
  \setbox2\hbox{%
  \special{pdf:literal q}%
  \special{pdf:literal -1 1 -0.2 4 0 -50 cm}\rlap{\copy0}
\special{pdf:literal Q}}%
    \hbox to --1\wd0{\kern--1\wd0\box2\hss}%
}

\rbox{abc $\mapsto $ xyz}


\bye
```

Substantive code adapted from [Scale text (\scalebox) in Plain TeX/XeTeX to make it narrower](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517990/scale-text-scalebox-in-plain-tex-xetex-to-make-it-narrower) via
[Left \mapsto arrow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638647/left-mapsto-arrow/638817#638817)

---

Some sort of reference example could be useful:

[image: example]

MWE

```
pdftex


   \vskip2ex%
   
\protected\def\rbox#1{%
  #1: %
  \setbox0\hbox{{abc}}%
  \setbox2\hbox{%
  \special{pdf:literal q}%
  \special{pdf:literal #1 cm}\rlap{\copy0}%
  \special{pdf:literal Q}%
}%
\hbox to --1\wd0{\kern1\wd0\box2\hss}%
\vrule
   \vskip1ex%
   }

no change: \rbox{1 0 0 1 0 0 }

translate: \rbox{1 0 0 1 50 35 }

scaling: \rbox{2 0 0 0.5 0 0 }

scaling: \rbox{0.5 0 0 2 0 0 }

reflection: \rbox{1 0 0 -1 0 0 }

reflection: \rbox{-1 0 0 -1 0 0 }

reflection: \rbox{-1 0 0 1 0 0 }

skew: \rbox{1 0.5 0 1 0 0 }

skew: \rbox{1 0 0.5 1 0 0 }

skew: \rbox{1 0 -0.5 1 0 0 }

skew: \rbox{1 -0.5 -0.5 1 0 0 } % 1 tan-x tan-y 1 0 0 

\vskip1ex
rotation: \rbox{1 1 -1 1 0 0 }

rotation: \rbox{-1 -1 1 -1 0 0 }

\vskip1ex
rotation: \rbox{0.86 0.5 -0.5 0.86 0 0 }%cos30 sin30 -sin30 cos30

\vskip1ex
rotation: \rbox{0.98 0.21 -0.21 0.98 0 0 } % -12 degrees

\protected\def\rboxc{%
  \setbox0\hbox{{abc}}%
  \setbox2\hbox{%
  \special{pdf:literal q}%
  \special{pdf:literal 2 0 0 2 0 0 cm}%scale
  \special{pdf:literal 1 0 -0.5 1 0 0 cm}%skew
  \special{pdf:literal 0.86 0.5 -0.5 0.86 0 0  cm}%rotate
  \special{pdf:literal -1 0 0 1 0 0 cm}{\copy0}%reflect
  \special{pdf:literal Q}%
  }%
\hbox to --1\wd0{\kern1\wd0\box2\hss}%
\vrule
   \vskip1ex%
   }

combined:


\rboxc


\bye
```